# How to make up a name - eighth day of week?

Tags: этимология

I'm planning to give a speech in Russian where I'll say something like "imagine there's an eighth day of the week--let's call it ______."

Представьте, что прибавился еще день недели--назовем его **восьмятница**.

What I'm struggling with is how to make up a name for the eighth day in a way that rings true for Russians in order to make the illustration more memorable.  However, I know I'm in dangerous territory as what a non-native speaker makes up as logical may not be what a native speaker would think of.

What would you name the eighth day of the week?  I would like to incorporate the number eight somehow.

Comment: what would you call it in English? coming up with an English name takes some creativity as well

Comment: I guess it's more difficult in English as none of actual weekdays refer to a number (like пятница in Russian refers to number 5). So it's unclear what would be the right way to embed a number into a weekday name.

Comment: This question is off-topic because - 1) Doesn't help anyone to learn Russian language since it's asking about a word that does not exists in Russian by definition 2) Can not have single accepted answer for obvious reasons

Comment: `Восьмёрник (?)` By analogy with *понедельник* and *вторник*
The logical problem with the name of the newly introduced eighth day is that *понедельник* in fact means `after sunday` (old Slavic name for sunday is [*неделя*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Понедельник#Этимология_и_именование_в_разных_традициях), and *нэдиля* in modern Ukrainian in particular, that is *inaction*). When you introduce the eighth day after sunday the name of *понедельник* becomes redundant as it would no longer follow *воскресенье* aka *неделя*.

Comment: To avoid the inconsistency the eighth day would have to be inserted after *пятница* or *суббота* at the latest but in this case its name could not derive from the numeral 8 for obvious reasons

Comment: @shabunc Maybe so, but the Russian learning community is small enough as it is without a lot of careful subdividing.  This is basically the only good place on the internet to ask Russian questions for advanced learners.  As far as points--I mean, these are made up internet points after all.  While there may be no correct way to make up a word there are incorrect ways.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I would definitely call it Octoday.  There are few prefixes more delightful in English than "octo"

Comment: @amerikashka this is why this question is closed but not deleted. I totally understand why you've decided to post it here but it's still off-topic. However comments can be helpful as well ;)

Comment: i would expect the English name of the eighth day to incorporate a name of another celestial body, octoday is inconsistent with the pattern of the other 7

Comment: @amerikashka: Terry Pratchett's Discworld's Octeday is usually translated as _осьмица_, albeit I like _восьмятница_ or _осмятница_ better for its obviously parody tone

Comment: yeah, *осьмица* sounds good, i tried to come up with something based on *осьм* instead of *восемь* but fell short

Comment: @amerikashka by the way, the names of the eighth day of week are a thing, so should you ask for their actual usage in Russian it would make an on-topic question.

Comment: For me осьмица sounds more like a name for a holiday rather than a day of week. As for понедельник relation to Sunday, I'd say that in modern language понедельник usually is understood as related to modern неделя (week), so it would sound fine if it doesn't follow a day that was called неделя quite a while ago

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Восьмятница sounds good actually. Maybe not for a case like "something happened and we have to have 8-day week, we need a name for the new day" (official name to be put into calendars and stuff). But for cases like you've described – just about perfect.

Comment: Thanks!  Восмерник was a close second but I stuck with the original and got good feedback afterwards.